# Display char elements of a structure in C

Tags: c, struct

Trying to display the char elements of my structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    char lastName[10];
    char firstName[10];
    char birthMonth[2];
    char birthDay[2];
    char birthYear[4];
} studentData;

int main()
{
    studentData admin={1111,"Brian","John","7","24","1960"};

    printf("ID: %d\n",admin.ID);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n",admin.lastName);
    printf("First Name: %s\n",admin.firstName);
    printf("Birth Month: %s\n",admin.birthMonth);
    printf("Birth Day: %s\n",admin.birthDay);
    printf("Birth Year: %s\n",admin.birthYear);
}
```

My results are:

```
ID: 1111
Last Name: Brian
First Name: John
Birth Month: 7
Birth Day: 241960▒E▒▒P@[▒_▒BP▒
Birth Year: 1960▒E▒▒P@[▒_▒BP▒
```

Why?

In addition:
The Combination of the birthMonth and birthDay should be a total of 4 bytes, I need to create a function to retrieve these bytes as an integer and print the result.Sorry that wasn't clear enough.I think the intent is to get the value locations byte by byte, and changing that (HEX) to Decimal and printing that out
How would I go about this?

eg for birthdate 01 and birthmonth 07 
the output would be

```
Address of Day: 0xbfb91f98
Address of Month: 0xbfb91f9a
Address of day and month is at address: bfb91f98
integer value of Day and Month is :925905200
```

Comment: `char birthMonth[2];
    char birthDay[2];
    char birthYear[4];` --> `char birthMonth[2+1];
    char birthDay[2+1];
    char birthYear[4+1];`

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want `birthMonth` and `birthDay` to look when they are printed out?

Comment: In the string chapter in your C book: look for text explaining null termination of strings.

Comment: @collins-- I see your edit to the last part of the question, but it is still unclear to me exactly what you are after. What, exactly, should the output be when you say "changing that (HEX) to Decimal and printing that out"? Show an example of the expected output. Again, there is no hex value to convert. The `char`s have values, which can be expressed in hex if you want, or in decimal. These are most likely UTF-8 values, which represent other values (e.g., **J**, or **7**).

Comment: @DavidBowling First of all i want to keep the Birthdate and birthmonth 2 bytes each so in total they will be 4 bytes, then i want to be able to convert the Ascii values of the inputs into Decimal value and output that value

Answer (score 2):

Your birthday is wrong. "24" is three characters with hidden \0 as string terminator. Try `char birthday[3];` and `char birthday[5];`

Your `birthYear` is also wrong. You need larger arrays. Even `birthMonth` will not work for October, November and December. Make that 3 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put '\0' at the end of char array to make it strings. birthMonth, birthDay and birthYear have no space for it. So add one more space for them.

```
   char birthMonth[3];
    char birthDay[3];
    char birthYear[5];
```

Comment: I am getting (null) for birth Day

Comment: Are you trying with same input `{1111,"Brian","John","7","24","1960"}`? If not make sure `lastName` and `firstName` are sufficient for your input. i.e. They can have at max 9 characters + '\0' I tested this with same input and it is working for me.

Comment: Check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ1BoNE9IdUJ4WHc

Comment: Worked :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you are not making enough space for the `\0` terminator at the end of each string. Add `+1` to your arrays, to accommodate space for `\0`.

Also, since you are using `int main()`, you need to `return 0` at the end, or this will just trigger unnecessary warnings in your code if you use `-Wall` during compilation.

You need to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAMESTRLEN 10
#define MONTHLEN 2
#define DAYLEN 2
#define YEARLEN 4

typedef struct 
{
    int ID;
    char lastName[NAMESTRLEN+1];
    char firstName[NAMESTRLEN+1];
    char birthMonth[MONTHLEN+1];
    char birthDay[DAYLEN+1];
    char birthYear[YEARLEN+1];
} studentData;

int main()
{
    studentData admin={1111,"Brian","John","7","24","1960"};

    printf("ID: %d\n",admin.ID);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n",admin.lastName);
    printf("First Name: %s\n",admin.firstName);
    printf("Birth Month: %s\n",admin.birthMonth);
    printf("Birth Day: %s\n",admin.birthDay);
    printf("Birth Year: %s\n",admin.birthYear);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ID: 1111
Last Name: Brian
First Name: John
Birth Month: 7
Birth Day: 24
Birth Year: 1960
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. any idea on the second part ?

Comment: "Also, since you are using int main(), you need to return 0 at the end, or this will just trigger unnecessary warnings in your code if you use -Wall during compilation. " No, this is incorrect. `main` is a special exception from all other functions, it doesn't need an explicit `return 0` statement. This was introduced to C in the year 1999. You should configure gcc correctly, use: `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` if you want it to behave as a standard C compiler for the year 2016, rather than a non-standard compiler for the year 1990. Or just upgrade to gcc 5.x, it uses gnu11 instead of gnu90.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty has been said about the need for adequate space in your character arrays. As for the final part of your question:

> In addition: The Combination of the birthMonth and birthDay should be
>   a total of 4 bytes, I need to retrieve these bytes as an integer and
>   print the result. How would I go about this?

I am not exactly sure what you want here. First, `birthMonth` and `birthDay` represent a combined total of 6 bytes, including the `NUL` terminators of the strings. You can convert these strings to numbers using, e.g, the `strtol()` function, and then you can work with the date information numerically. If you want to form a number from only the month and day numbers after this, that is easy.

The following code converts the strings `birthMonth`, `birthDay`, and `birthYear` to `long int`s, and then prints the date of birth in *month/day/year* format. Then the `bmonth` and `bday` `long`s are combined into one `long` to give single value, `birth_digits`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // for strtol()

typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    char lastName[11];
    char firstName[11];
    char birthMonth[3];
    char birthDay[3];
    char birthYear[5];
} studentData;

int main(void)
{
    studentData admin={1111,"Brian","John","7","24","1960"};
    long bmonth, bday, byear;
    long birth_digits;

    bmonth = strtol(admin.birthMonth, NULL, 10);
    bday = strtol(admin.birthDay, NULL, 10);
    byear = strtol(admin.birthYear, NULL, 10);

    printf("ID: %d\n",admin.ID);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n",admin.lastName);
    printf("First Name: %s\n",admin.firstName);
    printf("Birth Month: %s\n",admin.birthMonth);
    printf("Birth Day: %s\n",admin.birthDay);
    printf("Birth Year: %s\n",admin.birthYear);

    printf("DOB: %lu/%lu/%lu\n", bmonth, bday, byear);

    /* Convert bmonth and bday to one number */
    if (bday / 10) {
        birth_digits = bmonth * 100 + bday;
    } else {
        birth_digits = bmonth * 10 + bday;
    }

    printf("DOB Number: %lu\n", birth_digits);

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting program has this output:

```
ID: 1111
Last Name: Brian
First Name: John
Birth Month: 7
Birth Day: 24
Birth Year: 1960
DOB: 7/24/1960
DOB Number: 724
```

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear enough  i think the intent is to get the value locations byte by byte, and changing that (HEX) to Decimal and printing that out

Comment: You need to provide an example of exactly what you mean in your question. The value stored in, e.g., `birthMonth[1]` is not hex, but has a hex representation, and also a decimal representation. The decimal value of the `char` `birthMonth[1]` is 55 (probably-- if your system uses ASCII). Whatever the encoding, the value represented by `birthMonth[1]` is `birthMonth[1] - '0'`, which is 7.